# Launch desktop application from MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is there any way to launch desktop application like Internet Explorer from task of TFS build?

Comment: Just MSBuild or via TFS Build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFSBuild runs as a service and cannot launch interactive (i.e. Apps with a UI) applications.

Update: Apparently it's possible to configure TFS Build to run in interactive mode if you absolutely must: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181712.aspx#interactive

Answer (score 2):

You *can* but may not be what you are looking for.
Every process launched from a Windows (NT) Service runs on Session 0, invisible to a logged on user. Also the environment is peculiar and not recommended for automated testing.

You have two major options:

1. run the build agent in Interactive mode (see [Run your build server in interactive mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx)
2. use the test agent, again in Interactive mode (see [How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests that Interact with the Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Exec task?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) and pointing it to an executable you need?

```
<Target Name="RunIEForWhatEverReason">
    <Exec Command="explorer.exe"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: This task will be working if I run it locally. But when this task is launched with TFS build service, desktop application won't be started.

Comment: Also, I noticed TFS build service can launch console applications.